# How to use NOT IN SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all of the Id's which are not matched between tables, my SQL is:

```
SELECT UserP.*, AccountP.*
FROM UserP
    FULL JOIN AccountPON (UserP.Id = AccountP.Id)
WHERE UserP.Id NOT IN AccountP.Id
```

Comment: you want to find the ID which are not in the AccountPON table ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a sub query for this:

```
SELECT * FROM UserP WHERE Id NOT IN (select Id from AccountPON);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FULL OUTER JOIN` as you've done to find mismatches in BOTH sets. In a full outer join, the join key will be null on the side which is not matched, so the query needs to be changed to:

```
SELECT UserP.*, AccountP.*
FROM UserP FULL JOIN AccountPON ON UserP.Id = AccountP.Id
WHERE UserP.Id IS NULL OR AccountP.Id IS NULL;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/452a9/3)

The `WHERE Id NOT IN...` subqueries will only return you data which is in the LHS but not in the RHS table, which appears to only to solve half of what you are after - you would need to repeat the `NOT IN` for the RHS not in LHS, and then UNION the two results together, like so:

```
SELECT Id
FROM UserP
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM AccountPON)

UNION ALL

SELECT Id
FROM AccountPON
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM UserP);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from tableName where id not in ( 1,2,3)
```

It will bring all the records except those having id 1 or 2 or 3

```
IN is basically used as OR boolean operator in MYSQL.
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT IN :-** 
Specifies the search for an expression, based on whether the expression is included in or excluded from a list. The search expression can be a constant or a column name, and the list can be a set of constants or, more typically, a sub query. Enclose the list of values in parentheses

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserP
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id from AccountP)
```

**Refer to learn more :-**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx